# Get the logged user in a schedule task - Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, scheduled-tasks

I have a problem, because I want to access the user name that is logged within a method that is called in a schedule task. I have the following code:

```
 public void updateCategorizedProdutcsFile()
{
    Authentication authentication SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

If you can hel me i will be thankfull.

Comment: There is a whole [chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/concurrency.html) on that in the reference guide.

Comment: Do you have a web application or a Spring based java application ?

Comment: The concurrency chapter is moved here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/integrations/concurrency.html

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work.

```
public void updateCategorizedProdutcsFile()
{
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String name = auth.getName(); //get logged in username
}
```

Comment: the auth is null in this case